# Validate Wireless Connnection for a different user

Tags: login, wireless-access-point, windows-domain

Is it possible to validate to the wireless network as a different user to the one you're logged in as?

For example, I'm trying to connect to my works wireless network (there is currently no ethernet drvier installed so this is a no no) and i'm logging in under the local Administrator account and it keeps saying "Validating.." then it'll switch to "Authenticating user" but obviously this isn't going to work because it's a local user account and not one on the network. Is it possible for me to tell the wireless device to authenticate using my domain credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Even you could validate as another user, this may be not worth your time to solve.

In my similar experience, you should just contact the administrator of the network, and plead your case. There are normally a myriad of firewall/Active directory type sysadmin hurdles in which you will have to jump....

In short : accept your new adminstrator overlord.

Comment: I found out how to do it but i was unable to save the changes as the GPO set in place was not allowing me to do this. I found some peice of software already installed which took over control of my wireless and give me the option to enter in my domain credentials and i am now connected ok.